# Sort object by property value, but not with an array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort my Javascript object descending, but all solutions I see makes them into arrays (which I don't want). Here is my object:

```
var obj = {
    "and":2,
    "two":1,
    "too":1,
    "mother":3
}
```

I want this object to look like this instead:

```
var obj = {
    "mother":3
    "and":2,
    "two":1,
    "too":1
}
```

The property's name sorting doesn't matter, so I don't care about it being `two,too`. All I care about is the property's value being sorted. An ES6 friendly one-liner would be great, but it's definitely not required.

Thanks.

---

EDIT: I finally got something working, although it's really, really bad.. really bad.

```
function sortObject(obj) {
    var sortable=[];
    var newObject = {};
    for(var key in obj)
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            sortable.push([key, obj[key]]); // each item is an array in format [key, value]
    sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[1]-a[1];
    });
    for(i = 0; i < sortable.length; i++) {
        newObject[sortable[i][0]] = sortable[i][1];
    }
    return newObject;
}
```

I mean yeah it works, that's all that matters.

Comment: Object properties hold no order, so "sorting" an object makes no sense. You could just sort the array of keys.

Comment: And why would you want this ?

Comment: `srt=a=>{var o={};Object.keys(a).map(b=>o[b]=a[b]); return o}  ; srt({b:1,a:2});`

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Can you explain your motivation behind this question?

Comment: @Sirko: you are wrong, objects keep non-integer keys in insertion order. if you want to mutate, you can rewrite the above snip with `delete` to re-insert on an existing object...

Comment: I want to plot these objects into charts. Highest number and its property name being next to it.

Comment: @Snorlax: That's what an array is for.

Comment: i often use object key ordering to make API response show the important keys first...

Comment: @dandavis - are you saying objects **do** have order ?

Comment: @dandavis Objects have no reliable order. But some methods like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` do sort the properties. Other methods like `Object.keys` or `for...in` do not.

Comment: yeah, insertion order. officially since ES6 and realistically since Chrome5, with some minor exceptions.

Comment: @dandavis See [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/1529630) The answer is still "no".

Comment: [_Sort Map/Hash by values, retaining keys_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079323/sort-map-hash-by-values-retaining-keys)

Comment: [_How to sort object by number of properties in Javascript?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144234/how-to-sort-object-by-number-of-properties-in-javascript)

Comment: @dandavis As I'm too lazy to search for the exact part of the spec, I refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/1169798 . You here rely just on a implementation specific detail, which may change at any point.

Comment: well i wouldn't want to have order be make or break, but i find it reliable in practice to enhance literal presentation and pre-sort some naive template engine outputs. does my snip look ok in the console or not? we can argue semantics and specs, or we can just test the 1-liner to see how your system behaves. now if you want to talk about cross-platform order, that's a different beast...

Comment: @Oriol: i find `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` output unsorted, just like `Object.keys()` are we waiting on ES rollout?

Comment: So what you guys say is that it's impossible? I find that hard to believe :O

Comment: @dandavis If `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` does not sort the result your implementation is not ES6 compliant. First there should be integer indices in ascending numeric index order, and then other string properties in property creation order. `Object.keys` is not required to do that, but sometimes might use the same order, on some implementations.

Comment: @Snorlax: it's worth a shot to improve UX if it prevents forking a complex tool, but if you're trying to mimic a structure from another language, you better be sure about all the middle-ware iteration and 1,000,001 pesky gotchas and complicated rules.

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure how I would do this otherwise. What I have is basically a list of words (a sentence even). What I want is to count the amount of occurrences of the same word (like `the hamster, the monster, the best` would show `the: 3`, `hamster: 1` and so on). That seems like the perfect thing to put into an object.. no?

Comment: for what you describe, i've always maintained it should work just fine, or at least not hurt...

Comment: @dandavis So putting them inside an object is fine, but apparently it's impossible to sort an object on its property values?

Comment: well did my code help or not? if so then use it, if not, don't bother.

Comment: @dandavis Well nope. It doesn't do anything except print out the same object as I give it (or just `{b:1,a:2}` as you wrote).

Comment: well there's your answer; some part of the chart making doesn't use a known order iteration...

Comment: @dandavis w..what? The code you wrote doesn't even sort the object you wrote. My chart plotting works fine.

Comment: doh;`srt=a=>{var o={};Object.keys(a).sort().map(b=>o[b]=a[b]); return o} ; JSON.stringify(srt({b:1,a:2}));`; helps if you actually sort() ...

Comment: @dandavis Kinda works now... At least with the object you provided. But nope: https://jsfiddle.net/8ak0snsw/ - Inline `srt({and:2,two:1,too:1,mother:3})` doesn't work either.

Comment: @dandavis (because you are sorting on the key not the value)

Comment: @dandavis I think you understood this wrong. I want to sort on the VALUE not the KEY. Not the PROPERTY but the PROPERTY VALUE. My example was pretty good and easy to understand.